# How to update WPF UI at deserialization of "settings" object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, deserialization

My goal is to do this: User selects settings file, settings are read and the UI is updated correspondingly. Saving should also be possible obviously.

My program is currently not WPF/XAML and doing this now would mean a lot of repetition and added work when new settings are required.

So someone told me WPF/XAML was the way to go, I looked into it and liked it but I'm still not sure how to do what I want. The advantage of WPF/XAML is of course data bindings, but if I want to read a whole settings file I'd probably replace the old settings object with a new one. Can I make a WPF program react to this and update fields according to some given data bindings?

I'm mostly interested in wether this is good design and if not - what is.

Comment: data bindings existed long before wpf/xaml - *personally* I'd need more reason that "settings" to move between stacks...

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. First of all, your settings object should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface. This basically adds an event, that is called everytime you call a property setter. That way binding to non dependency properties works both ways. You don't really need that interface. But if you want your changes after the first set(where all properties are read) to be reflected in the ui, you need that interface.

i usually use a base class for that

```
public class PropertyChangedNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { mPropertyChanged += value; }
        remove { mPropertyChanged -= value; }
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string aPropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = mPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aPropertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private PropertyChangedEventHandler mPropertyChanged;
}
```

Your settings should now be derived from that class.

```
class MySettings : PropertyChangedNotifier
{
 public string UserName
 {
  get{return mUserName;}
  set{mUserName=value; RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");}
 }
}
```

Now for the ui, DataBinding is always related to the set `DataContext`.

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow">

<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
</StackPanel>

</Window>
```

The textbox will try to get its value from the current set datacontext from the property "UserName". Now to set the DataContext we could do that in the mainwindow code behind.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = ReadMyUserSettings();
}
```

If you change your Datacontext any time, the ui updates automatically.
And your changes to the textbox will be written back to your settings. This can also be improved by adding some sort of cancel and save workflow, so that you settings are not changed if the user hit cancel. See `IEditableObject` and `BindingGroup` for that.

Hope that gives you a rough idea, how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, using a very simple example in c#-like pseudocode using the MVVM pattern.

First, I'd define my Models, which define my configuration and are serialized/deserialized.  I prefer to do this using the [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx).

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

My ViewModel would have a public property that holds the current instance of this configuration

```
public sealed class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    #region Person
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for <see cref="Person"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            PersonPropertyName,
            typeof(Person),
            typeof(ViewModel),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the <see cref="Person"/> <see cref="DependencyProperty"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public const string PersonPropertyName = "Person";

    /// <summary>
    /// The Person
    /// </summary>
    public string Person
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(PersonProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(PersonProperty , value); }
    }
    #endregion      

    // snip
```

In my `ViewModel` I would also have an [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) for Loading and Saving the configuration.  There are plenty of quesitons here about the common implementation of an ICommand which delegates execution of `CanExecute` and `Execute` to the ViewModel.

In your UI, you simply bind to the public properties of your configuration Model through the ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="Herp.DerpWindow" SnipXamlForBrevity="true">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel xmlns="clr-namespace:Herp" />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <!-- and later... -->
  <Label>The Person in Question:</Label>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name}" />
  <Label>Age</Label>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Age}" />
```

Because the configuration Model is held in a public DependencyProperty of the ViewModel, as you replace it the UI is automatically updated with the new values.  You can, of course, use INotifyPropertyChanged as an alternate method of notifying the UI of binding updates, but I prefer to keep it simple.